unicorn command is not working: fastapi python
I'm trying to set up a FastAPI application using Docker and docker-compose. However, I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError when I attempt to run the application. Here's how I've configured my docker-compose.yml and main.py.
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build:
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./app/file:/app/file
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from .api.router import router as api_router
from .core.config import settings

app = FastAPI(title="API", openapi_url=f"{settings.API_V1_STR}/openapi.json")

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Allow all domains
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Allow all HTTP methods
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

app.include_router(api_router, prefix=settings.API_V1_STR)

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"message": "Welcome to the API!"}

Error Message:
web-1  | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
web-1  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
web-1  | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using WatchFiles
web-1  | Process SpawnProcess-1:
web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

I tried adding PYTHONPATH to the Docker environment but it did not resolve the issue. Could someone help me figure out what might be going wrong here?
Thank you!

maybe you should use name app.py instead of main.py

what did you add to PYTHONPATH? It has to be path without app - like /full/path/to/folder instead of /full/path/to/folder/app

You could try specifying the app dir like uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload --app-dir ./app

Try to change this line:
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload

to this:
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload

